# Obtener registro entre rangos de fechas con LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo una tabla con registros que mantienen reservas de horas tomadas por pacientes, en base a un ID. y que por cada registro se establece una hora en formato DateTime (DD/MM/AAAA HH:MM:ss:MSS)
En un servicio ApiRest (en c#) estoy recibiendo como parámetro una entidad con los siguientes datos

```
{
    "Usuario" : "Usuario test",
    "Inicio" : "2019-03-07 10:30:00", 
    "Reserved" : "false"
}
```

Para poder agregar el registro en la tabla, debo validar que la hora entregada como parámetro mas 1 hora, no se encuentre dentro del rango horario de la base en algún registro. Es decir:

Si en la base existen los siguientes registros

```
Usuario, HoraReserva, Reserved
User1, 2019/03/07 08:00:00, true
User1, 2019/03/07 10:00:00, true
User1, 2019/03/07 15:00:00, true
```

La consulta debería devolverme el 2do registro ya que como la entidad pasada como parámetro tiene las 10:30:00 al sumar 1 hora su fin sería a las 11:30:00, y este rango de horas estaría dentro del rango de horas (hora de inicio + 1 hora) del segundo registro.

He estado intentando con la siguiente consulta, pero no me trae registros.

```
DateTime Inicio = Parametro.Inicio;
DateTime termino = Parametro.Inicio.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
var result = _context.Horas.Where(x => x.Inicio >= Inicio && x.Inicio.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0)) <= termino);
```

La fecha corresponde, pero no es posible ubicar el rango horario del 2do registro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no te entrega ningún registro por que no hay ningún registro que cumpla lo siguiente

```
var result = _context.Horas.Where(x => x.Inicio >= '10:30' && x.Inicio.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0))  <= '11:30');
```

si bien tienes un registro mayor a las 1030 (el registro de las 15), agregas al where que ese registro además sea menor a las 1130 (termino), por lo cual ningún registro cumple.

para que cumpla la condición que necesitas debes agregar +1 hora a x.inicio de comparación con la fecha de input (10:30) y agregar un `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
var result = _context.Horas.Where(x => x.Inicio.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0)) >= Inicio && x.Inicio.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0)) <= termino).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Estimado, muchisimas gracias por la ayuda.. la verdad es que a estas alturas de la semana, me cuesta ver hasta la puerta de salida. Te Agradezco mucho. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

No estas tomando en cuenta el horario de 10:30 por eso no tienes nada, aqui agrego una solucion suponiendo una clase Horario:

```
 class Horario {
        public Horario(string id, string horaInicio,bool estaReservado)
        {
            UsuarioID = id;
            HoraInicio = DateTime.Parse(horaInicio);
            esReservado = estaReservado;
        }
        public string  UsuarioID { get; set; }
        public DateTime HoraInicio { get; set; }
        public bool esReservado { get; set; }
    }
```

La consulta sera de la siguiente manera rangoHora=1 una hora de ventana.
horaVerificar es tu horario de entrada.

```
      var usuarios = new List<Horario>()
                {
                  new Horario("user1","2019/03/07 08:00:00",true),
                  new Horario("user2","2019/03/07 10:00:00",true),
                  new Horario("user3", "2019/03/07 15:00:00",true)
                };

                var horaVerficar = DateTime.Parse("2019/03/07 10:30:00");
                var rangoHoras = 1;

                var horariosReservados= usuarios.Where(x => x.HoraInicio < horaVerficar && horaVerficar < x.HoraInicio.AddHours(rangoHoras)).ToList();

   // horariosReservados con un item de salida
```